# Convolution of two modified Bessel functions $K_{0}\left(\left|x\right|\right)$

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, bessel-functions

Given two normally distributed variables $X,Y$ in $\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$, it is stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Independent_central-normal_distributions) that the product distribution of $Z=XY$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind

$$f_{Z}\left(z\right)=\dfrac{K_{0}\left(\left|z\right|\right)}{\pi}$$

Now given two variables $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ with this Bessel distribution, I was wondering if there is a close-form expression for the distribution of their sum $Z=Z_{1}+Z_{2}$. This boils down to evaluating the convolution

$$f_{Z}\left(z\right)=\dfrac{1}{\pi^{2}}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}q\;K_{0}\left(\left|q\right|\right)K_{0}\left(\left|z-q\right|\right)$$

---

This problem originates in atomic physics in the study of absorption lines. The transverse components of the wave-vector of a finite Gaussian beam are distributed normally. Also the velocities of thermal atoms follow a normal distribution. I am looking for the distribution of the Doppler shift $\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}=k_{x}v_{x}+k_{y}v_{y}$.

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathbb E(e^{i w Z_1}) = 1/\sqrt {w^2 + 1}$. The sum $Z_1 + Z_2$ has a Laplace distribution (I assume all $k_i$ and $v_i$ are independent).

Comment: @Maxim I see, thanks! So the characteristic function of the sum is a Lorentzian, and as a result the distribution of the sum is simply exponential.